# How to get the total count/length of the following div tag

Tags: javascript, xpath, count, protractor

Here is the tag:

```
  <div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rack-inner" style="height: 588px;"><!----><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition1 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 574px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">1</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition2 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 560px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">2</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition3 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 546px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">3</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition4 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 532px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">4</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition5 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 518px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">5</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition6 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 504px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">6</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition7 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 490px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">7</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition8 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 476px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">8</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition9 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 462px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">9</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition10 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 448px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">10</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition11 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 434px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">11</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition12 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 420px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">12</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition13 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 406px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">13</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition14 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 392px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">14</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition15 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 378px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">15</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition16 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 364px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">16</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition17 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 350px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">17</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition18 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 336px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">18</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition19 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 322px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">19</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition20 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 308px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">20</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition21 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 294px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">21</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition22 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 280px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">22</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition23 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 266px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">23</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition24 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 252px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">24</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition25 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 238px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">25</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition26 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 224px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">26</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition27 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 210px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">27</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition28 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 196px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">28</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition29 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 182px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">29</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition30 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 168px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">30</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition31 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 154px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">31</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition32 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 140px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">32</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition33 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 126px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">33</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition34 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 112px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">34</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition35 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 98px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">35</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition36 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 84px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">36</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition37 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 70px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">37</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition38 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 56px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">38</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition39 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 42px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">39</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition40 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 28px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">40</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition41 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 14px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">41</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="UPositionContainer ng-tns-c13-6 uPosition42 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 15px;"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="mount-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-left"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rail rail-right"></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="uposLabel"><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-6">42</div></div></div><div _ngcontent-c13="" class="rack-item-container"><!----><rack-item _ngcontent-c13="" _nghost-c20="" class="ng-tns-c13-6 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 308px; height: 42px; z-index: 0; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div _ngcontent-c20=""><dnd _ngcontent-c20=""></dnd><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-style-wrapper ng-star-inserted stage-EXISTING facing-away type-ups uheight-3" style="position: absolute; height: 42px; width: 136px; left: 0px;"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-left ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-right ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-mounted ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="generic-rack-mount-equipment-style-wrapper"><!----></div></div><!----><!----></div></div></rack-item><!----><rack-item _ngcontent-c13="" _nghost-c20="" class="ng-tns-c13-6 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 168px; height: 28px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div _ngcontent-c20=""><dnd _ngcontent-c20=""></dnd><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-style-wrapper ng-star-inserted stage-EXISTING facing-out type-ups uheight-2" style="position: absolute; height: 28px; width: 150px; left: 0px;"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-left ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-right ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-mounted ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="generic-rack-mount-equipment-style-wrapper"><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-label ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="name text-ellipsis midwayGeneric">APC Smart-UPS 1500VA LCD RM 2U 120V</div><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="info text-ellipsis"><!----></div></div></div></div><!----><!----></div></div></rack-item><rack-item _ngcontent-c13="" _nghost-c20="" class="ng-tns-c13-6 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 42px; height: 42px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div _ngcontent-c20=""><dnd _ngcontent-c20=""></dnd><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-style-wrapper ng-star-inserted stage-EXISTING facing-out type-ups uheight-3" style="position: absolute; height: 42px; width: 150px; left: 0px;"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-left ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-right ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-mounted ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="generic-rack-mount-equipment-style-wrapper"><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-label ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="name text-ellipsis midwayGeneric">APC Smart-UPS SRT 5000VA RM 208V</div><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="info text-ellipsis"><!----></div></div></div></div><!----><!----></div></div></rack-item><rack-item _ngcontent-c13="" _nghost-c20="" class="ng-tns-c13-6 ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute; top: 378px; height: 42px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><div _ngcontent-c20=""><dnd _ngcontent-c20=""></dnd><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-style-wrapper ng-star-inserted stage-EXISTING facing-out type-ups uheight-3" style="position: absolute; height: 42px; width: 150px; left: 0px;"><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-left ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="mount-right ng-star-inserted"></div><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-mounted ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="generic-rack-mount-equipment-style-wrapper"><!----><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="rack-item-label ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="name text-ellipsis midwayGeneric">APC Smart-UPS SRT 5000VA RM 208V</div><div _ngcontent-c20="" class="info text-ellipsis"><!----></div></div></div></div><!----><!----></div></div></rack-item></div></div>
```

i am using the following xpath which actually returns the total length as 42 manually when i search in the inspect element. However i need to get the length of this xpath ie,

```
 by.xpath(//div/div/div[2]/rack/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div).count(). I tried with this expect this is not returning the total count
```

I know that this xpath turns total count of 42. But i need to automation in such a way that it would get the count of  the resulting xpath

Answer (score 0):

`by.xpath(...)` returns a `Locator` object, that you can then use to retrieve elements.
`browser.element(theLocator)` will give the first element it finds;
`browser.element.all(theLocator)` will give all matching elements;

You need to use `browser.element.all(by.xpath(...))`:

```js
const targetXpath: string = "//div/div/div[2]/rack/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div";
const targetLocator: Locator = by.xpath(targetXpath);
const elemArray: ElementArrayFinder = browser.element.all(targetLocator);
const elemCount: number = await elemArray.count();
```

Also I think your xpath might be over complicated, you could use something like the following:

```js
const targetXpath = "//div[@class='rack-inner')]";
```